# How can I find out the four unique random numbers in Android within the range of 1 to 60?

Tags: java, android

This is what I tried so far in my app.

I got this code by searching it from Google.

Inside the Button OnClick() I called the Arandom() method:

```
public void Arandom(View view) {
    final int SET_SIZE_REQUIRED = 4;
    final int NUMBER_RANGE = 70;
        Random random = new Random();

        Set set = new HashSet<Integer>(SET_SIZE_REQUIRED);

        while(set.size()< SET_SIZE_REQUIRED) {

            while (set.add(random.nextInt(NUMBER_RANGE)) != true) ;
        }
        assert set.size() == SET_SIZE_REQUIRED;
    ArrayList<Integer> Elements =  new ArrayList<>(set);
    Log.i("Elements","A:" + Elements.get(0));
    Log.i("Elements","B:" + Elements.get(1));
    Log.i("Elements","C:" + Elements.get(2));
    Log.i("Elements","D:" + Elements.get(3));

    }
```

Now I am able to get four unique random numbers by this code but the problem is there sum is greater then 60. Let me explain it little bit.

When I run the code I get:

```
A:61

B:45

C:31

D:49
```

[This is the screen shot of my log cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m7Kf.png)

So I want the sum of all the numbers should be in the specified range (which is 1 to 60).

e.g: A = 20 , B = 25 , C = 3 and D = 11 then their sum is 59 which is within the range

Now another e.g: Suppose A = 5 , B = 22 , C = 18 and D = 3  then their sum will be 48

When we Add A,B,C,D then their sum should not exceed the range that is 60

I am new to Android and Java, and I am learning on my own by searching some materials on Google.

Comment: You could take 60, divide it by the sum and multiply that number for each of the values.

Comment: Why not simply generate 4 numbers with a maximum of 15 each ?

Comment: The question doesn't really state how important it is to get close to 60.

Comment: Dennis Reep please can you explain Little bit more by some Code Example

Comment: @RamuKumar Check out my answer for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your target sum is T. It's easiest if you try to pick the numbers in descending order (you can shuffle them afterwards, if you want).

The largest number you can pick for the 1st of four numbers is `T-6`, because you need to pick 3, 2 and 1 for the smaller numbers.

The smallest number you can pick is the one where `n+(n-1)+2+1 = T`, so `T/2+1`.

So, pick the first number in the range `(T/2+1)` to `T-6`.

Then repeat the process to pick the third-largest and second-largest, applying similar logic to determine the possible range. There should be no choice in the smallest number, it's just whatever else you need to add to make the final sum.

Note that you need to take care with rounding of things like the `T/2`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the return type an `int[]`. You know how big you want to make the set, so there is no need to use sets or lists. The input parameter is changed to SET_SIZE_REQUIRED instead of using view. Make sure that a funtion only has one purpose and not do a calculation and change on a view at the same time.

Replace the `60f` to something else if you want the sum to be more or less than 60.

```
public int[] Arandom(int numberOfValues) {
    int[] values = new int[numberOfValues];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
        values[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        sum += values[i];
    }

    float multiplier = 60f / sum;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
        values[i] = (int)(values[i] * multiplier);
        Log.i("Value " + (i + 1), values[i]);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Or just do this:

```
public int[] Arandom(int numberOfValues) {
    int[] values = new int[numberOfValues];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
        values[i] = (int)(Math.random() * (60f / numberOfValues));
        Log.i("Value " + (i + 1), values[i]);
    }
    return values;
}
```